# Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fann

Здравствуйте, подключаю библиотеку FANNCSharp.Float.
При запуске проекта выдается такая ошибка:

Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "FANNCSharp.Float, Version=0.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" либо одну из их зависимостей. Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.

Файлы лежат в папке с проектом. Этот файл я добавил в ссылки. Все должно работать...
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?
Версия Fraemwork 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

Предположу, что вы забыли положить нативную зависимую библиотеку в каталог с программой. Согласно [документации](https://github.com/joelself/FannCSharp), это файл `fannfloat.dll` (для Release-версии) или `fannfloatd.dll` (для Debug-версии). На той же странице эти файлы можно и загрузить, если что.